# Laravel Homestead - SSL set up

Tags: ssl, laravel, vagrant

I'm trying to start to use vagrant for development - I'm completely new to using vagrant for my development - relying on an apache/php/mysql set up on a laptop.

I'm developing using laravel and have set up homestead and am up and running.

I've tried to enable SSL on the homestead (box?) and followed these instructions to set up: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04

I made the changes to the homestead sites_enabled file for the site i'm working on.

I added port 443 just beneath port 80 within the server,added the entries for SSL On etc

I've restarted the nginx server and am able to see my pages using https (although chrome doesn't like the certificate)

If I then try to access pages using http I get a 400 error `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`

so  a few questions:
1. how can I alter the set up to use a combination of HTTP and HTTPS requests?
2. is it bad practice to serve a site with a combination of HTTP and HTTPS requests - should I simply serve the whole site as https?

Very confused to a completely new subject

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

### Add port forwarding to homestead 1.x

You need to forward the SSL port by adding a new line to homestead.rb

```bash
sudo nano /vagrant/scripts/homestead.rb  
# add SSL port forwarding ...
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 44300
```

### Create SSL certificate

#### Steps one to four

Do the **steps one** to **step four** only from this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04

#### Step five - Set up the certificate

Edit your homestead site you are working on (replace example with your existing site)

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example
```

Duplicate the whole `server{…}` section (not only the `listen` line as you did).
In the duplicated section edit `listen 80` to `listen 443`.

Before the end of the section add the following lines:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
```

`exit` and do a `vagrant reload`.

Be careful with `--provision`. The changes to `sites-available/example` you just made are reset to default.

If you need to make the changes permanently even in case of provisioning, then have a look at the `serve.sh` located at your host's homestead folder `homstead/scripts/serve.sh` and edit it equally to step 5.

Use `https://your.domain:44300` in your browser to access via SSL. Accept the self signed certificate in your browser if necessary.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I'll give this a go at the weekend

Comment: Nice addition, but how can we solve the 'Red cross' not trusted not verified by third party? Via laravel homestead local

Comment: Self created certificates always produce the not trusted sign until you accept it in your browser. You can buy a certificate from a trusted certificate authority to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Peh. I did not get it working with the above code:

I did need to remove

```
SSL on
```

and add the ssl to the listener

```
listen 443 ssl;
```