# Cannot accept self signed certificate in Safari 11 to access Vagrant / Homestead local site

Tags: ssl, safari, vagrant, homestead, macos-high-sierra

I installed Vagrant and Homestead to test my app locally. Everything works correctly when I access `http://mysite.app` in Firefox and Chrome. However, Safari won't let me use the `http` / non secure version of the site and will automatically redirect me to the secure (https) version. For example, when accessing `http://mysite.app`, I get redirected to `https://mysite.app`.

Other browsers (Firefox and Chrome) doesn't redirect me and I can use the standard, non secure version. So it's not a redirect enforced by the server.

The redirection itself wouldn't really be an issue if Safari would let me access the `https` version. Since it's a local dev environment, the SSL certificate is self signed and Safari won't allows me to access a site with a non trusted certificate. So in the end, I always get a `Safari can't establish a secure connection` error when using Safari to access this Vagrant site.

[image: Result page]

Safari doesn't offer a way (anymore?) to accept the self signed certificate. Again, this is not an issue with Chrome or Firefox since they allow you to add an exception right from the browser.

Any idea how I can make Safari use the `http` version of the site **or** make Safari trust the self signed certificate ?

FYI, I'm using Safari 11.0.2 on High Sierra 10.13.2 Beta. Same result on iMac and MacbookAir, so it's not computer related.

Comment: FYI, this now affect most recent version of Google Chrome. They too seams to have removed the ability to add an exception from the browser.

Comment: actually it appears Chrome still includes this but NOT for .dev domains as of version 63 - 12/7/2018 (https://webdevstudios.com/2017/12/12/google-chrome-63/). While slashing through the weeds on this on my local enviro I found that there is no longer a "Visit site anyways..." option when visiting a .dev site, but when I change it to .localhost there is...

Comment: Good to know. Looks like the default Homestead `.app` is now invalid too. I’ll see to use `.localhost` in the future.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While I didn't found why Safari wants to force SSL and doesn't want to use the non secure (http) version of my site on this Vagrant/Homestead box (like Firefox or Chrome), I found a way to mark the self signed site certificate as trusted in MacOS Keychain Access.

Note that shouldn't be an issue with prior version of MacOS since Safari used to allow you to add an exception directly in the browser and continue to a site with an invalid SSL certificate. This options seams to be gone in Safari 11 (High Sierra).

So a solution to access my Vagrant website [is to save the site certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060726/445757)  on the host computer (using an ssh connection to the Vagrant box or another Browser), add it to the Keychain and mark it as trusted.

However, another issue regarding *Keychain Access* came up. While this used to work in earlier version of MacOS, under High Sierra (or at least 10.13.2 Beta), **the ability to mark a certificate as trusted from the Keychain Access app is gone**. On both my iMac and MacbookAir, double clicking on the certificate added to the Keychain **does absolutely nothing**. Even clicking `Get Info` from the contextual menu doesn't bring the ability to edit the certificate.

[A workaround for this](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/pull/527#issuecomment-288606853) is to use the command line to mark the certificate as trusted. Using Terminal, `cd` to the directory where the certificate is saved on your computer and run this command :

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain example.app.cer
```

Change `example.app.cer` with the name of your certificate. This will mark the certificate as trusted in *Keychain Access* and allows you to visit the local site as if it was signed with a valid certificate.

**tl;dr** Add the site certificate taken from the Vagrant/Homestead box to the keychain, run the command and just use https connexion.

Answer (score 8):

The previous answer isn't completely correct. macOS High Sierra *has* the ability to trust a certificate via the Keychain Access app, so no CLI necessary.

Steps:

1. Open Keychain Access app and find your certificate.
2. File->Get Info
3. Open Trust menu inside of info window (Note the triangle disclosure to the left of the word Trust.)
4. Set When using this certificate to "Always Trust".

Done.

Comment: Hum... Can't test for sure, but look like they **added back** the ability to mark a certificate as trusted in a recent update (at least 10.13.5-beta). As stated in my previous answer, it didn't use to work in High Sierra 10.13.2 Beta.

Comment: And note that if you're doing something like using a generated self-signed cert inside a VM, you need to copy the generated cert file to your computer, then open it in Keychain Access, then click on it, then do the Get Info / Trust settings. Once that's done the page will load without exceptions.

Comment: This worked for me on MacOs Monterey 12.6