# How to get https certificate working on local Laravel Homestead site

Tags: laravel, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, homestead

I'm getting this problem:

[image]

The error that I'm seeing in Windows 10 Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) is:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your
> information from ((mysite)) (for example, passwords,
> messages, or credit cards). Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
>
> This page is not secure (broken HTTPS).
>
> Certificate - missing
>
> This
> site is missing a valid, trusted certificate
> (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

Firefox Quantum 59.0.2 (64-bit) says:

> Your connection is not secure
>
> The owner of ((mysite)) has configured their website
> improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has
> not connected to this website.
>
> Connection is Not Secure
>
> Could not verify this certificate because the
> issuer is unknown.

I have already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755133/470749

```
vboxmanage --version
5.2.6r120293

vagrant -v
Vagrant 2.0.2

git branch
* (HEAD detached at v7.3.0)

vagrant box list
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 5.2.0)

vagrant box update
==> vboxHomestead: Checking for updates to 'laravel/homestead'
    vboxHomestead: Latest installed version: 5.2.0
    vboxHomestead: Version constraints: >= 5.2.0
    vboxHomestead: Provider: virtualbox
==> vboxHomestead: Box 'laravel/homestead' (v5.2.0) is running the latest version.
```

I wonder if this means that I'm not yet using [release 7.1.0](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases/tag/v7.1.0) (which has in its changelog "sign SSL certificates with a custom root certificate"), and I wonder if that's why I have this SSL HTTPS problem.

What are the next steps I should try now to get the certificate working?

Comment: Homestead 5.1.0 seems to be the latest available here: https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead. I'm very confused. What is the 7.1.2 referring to?

Comment: Can you provide us with output from `echo | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -servername localhost`? Additionally, output of `echo | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -servername localhost | openssl x509 -text -noout` may come in handy. Correct domain and port if needed.

Comment: @x-yuri Yes, but the output is long. What should I be looking for? `echo | openssl s_client -connect kvb.test:443 -servername kvb.test
CONNECTED(000001A0)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/O=Vagrant/C=UN/CN=kvb.test
   i:/O=Vagrant/C=UN/CN=Homestead vboxHomestead Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE7TCCA (... and much more...)`

Comment: "What should I be looking for?" Not sure yet. Can you create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with the output and give me a link to it? Or use some pastebin?

Comment: Any solution for latest vagrant version in MAC?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have an easy way of checking it on Windows, so I'm going to use VirtualBox running on Linux here. Install `vagrant`, then:

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git
$ cd homestead
$ git checkout v7.3.0
$ bash init.sh
```

I've simplified `Homestead.yaml` a bit (you might prefer to stick with the defaults):

```yaml
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
provider: virtualbox
folders:
    - map: /home/yuri/_/la1
      to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
```

Then:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/_/la1/public
$ echo '<?php echo "it works";' > ~/_/la1/public/index.php

$ vagrant up

$ vagrant ssh -c 'ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled'
homestead.test

$ vagrant ssh -c 'cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/homestead.test'
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name .homestead.test;
    root "/home/vagrant/code/public";
    ...
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.test.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.test.key;
}
```

As we can see it has the certificates in `/etc/nginx/ssl`:

```
$ vagrant ssh -c 'ls -1 /etc/nginx/ssl'
ca.homestead.homestead.cnf
ca.homestead.homestead.crt
ca.homestead.homestead.key
ca.srl
homestead.test.cnf
homestead.test.crt
homestead.test.csr
homestead.test.key
```

I tried to trust server certificate systemwide, but it didn't work out. It appeared on Servers tab in Firefox' Certificate Manager, but that didn't make Firefox trust it. I could probably have added an exception, but trusting CA certificates looks like a better option. Trusting CA certificate makes browser trust any certificate they issue (new sites running under Homestead). So we're going to go with CA certificate here:

```
$ vagrant ssh -c 'cat /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.homestead.homestead.crt' > ca.homestead.homestead.crt

$ sudo trust anchor ca.homestead.homestead.crt

$ trust list | head -n 5
pkcs11:id=%4c%f9%25%11%e5%8d%ad%5c%2a%f3%63%b6%9e%53%c4%70%fa%90%4d%77;type=cert
    type: certificate
    label: Homestead homestead Root CA
    trust: anchor
    category: authority
```

Then, I've added `192.168.10.10  homestead.test` to `/etc/hosts`, restarted Chromium, and it worked:

[image]

P.S. I'm running Chromium 65.0.3325.162, and Firefox 59.0.

#### Windows

Apparently, Windows doesn't have `trust` utility. Under Windows one has [two stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/local-machine-and-current-user-certificate-stores): Local Machine and Current User Certificate stores. No point in using Local Machine Certificate Store, since we're making it work just for our current user. Then, there are substores. With two predefined of them being of most interest: Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Intermediate Certification Authorities Stores. Commonly referred in command line as [root and CA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can access Chrome's Certificate Manager by following chrome://settings/?search=Manage%20certificates, then clicking Manage certificates. Of most interest are Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Intermediate Certification Authorities tabs.

One way to manager certificates is via [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil):

```
>rem list Current User > Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
>certutil.exe -store -user root

>rem list Local Machine > Intermediate Certification Authorities store
>certutil.exe -store -enterprise CA

>rem GUI version of -store command
>certutil.exe -viewstore -user CA

>rem add certificate to Current User > Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
>certutil.exe -addstore -user root path\to\file.crt

>rem delete certificate from Current User > Trusted Root Certification Authorities store by serial number
>certutil.exe -delstore -user root 03259fa1

>rem GUI version of -delstore command
>certutil.exe -viewdelstore -user CA
```

The results are as follows (for both Local Machine and Current User Certificate stores):

```
root
    homestead.test.crt
        error
    ca.homestead.homestead.crt
        appears in Trusted Root Certification Authorities tab
CA
    homestead.test.crt
        doesn't work, appears in Other People tab
    ca.homestead.homestead.crt
        doesn't work, appears in Intermediate Certification Authorities tab
```

Other options would be double-clicking on a certificate in Explorer, importing certificates from Chrome's Certificate Manager, using Certificates MMC Snap-in (run `certmgr.msc`), or using [`CertMgr.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/certmgr-exe-certificate-manager-tool).

For those who have `grep` installed, here's how to quickly check where is the certificate:

```
>certutil.exe -store -user root | grep "homestead\|^root\|^CA" ^
& certutil.exe -store -user CA | grep "homestead\|^root\|^CA" ^
& certutil.exe -store -enterprise root | grep "homestead\|^root\|^CA" ^
& certutil.exe -store -enterprise CA | grep "homestead\|^root\|^CA"
```

So, installing CA certificate into Current User > Trusted Root Certification Authorities store seems like the best option. And **make sure** not to forget to [restart your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145936/chrome-active-content-with-certificate-errors/46390363#46390363).

#### more in-depth explanation of how it works

In `Vagrantfile` it requires [`scripts/homestead.rb`](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/v7.3.0/Vagrantfile#L15), then runs [`Homestead.configure`](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/v7.3.0/Vagrantfile#L35). That's the method, that configures `vagrant` to make all the needed preparations.

There we can [see](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/v7.3.0/scripts/homestead.rb#L196-L262):

```rb
if settings.include? 'sites'
    settings["sites"].each do |site|

        # Create SSL certificate
        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
            s.name = "Creating Certificate: " + site["map"]
            s.path = scriptDir + "/create-certificate.sh"
            s.args = [site["map"]]
        end

        ...

        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
            ...
            s.path = scriptDir + "/serve-#{type}.sh"
            ...
        end

        ...
    end
end
```

So, these [two](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/v7.3.0/scripts/create-certificate.sh) [files](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/v7.3.0/scripts/serve-laravel.sh) create certificate and `nginx` config respectively.

#### further reading

[How to make browser trust localhost SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553299/52499)

Comment: It's *great* to see a screenshot of the green lock next to `https://homestead.test` in your address bar. However, the only relevant steps are to first copy `/etc/nginx/ssl/ca.homestead.homestead.crt` from my Homestead Vagrant box into a path that is reachable on Windows and then run an equivalent of `sudo trust anchor ca.homestead.homestead.crt`. So this is where I'm stuck now:

Comment: When I run Windows Command Prompt as an admin and try to run that `trust anchor` command, I get this error: `p11-kit: couldn't complete writing file: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/pki/ca-trust/source\Homestead_vboxHomestead_Root_CA.p11-kit: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't create object: The operation failed`

Comment: Ahh, we might be getting closer. I ran `certutil -addstore -enterprise -f "Root" ca.homestead.vboxHomestead.crt` from a Windows Command Prompt as Admin, and now Chrome's error is different: `This page is not secure (broken HTTPS).
Resources - active content with certificate errors
You have recently allowed content loaded with certificate errors (such as scripts or iframes) to run on this site.`

Comment: @Ryan Try to make use of [`CertMgr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/certmgr). `CertMgr /s /r localMachine`, `CertMgr /s /r currentUser` to list certificates. `CertMgr /add homestead.test.crt /s /r currentUser root` to add a certificate. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/certificate-stores). Not sure if browsers consult those stores though. Most likely, if they do you'll find the CA certificate under Authorities tab of browser's Certificate Manager.

Comment: I'll award the bounty because of your effort (especially your screenshot of the green lock, which gave me hope that it was possible). I think ultimately the steps I was missing were: use Windows Command Prompt as Admin to run `certutil -addstore -enterprise -f "Root" ca.homestead.vboxHomestead.crt`. Then it still didn't work, but I went to lunch, and when I returned and woke my computer up, it worked. It's working for my local site even though I'm using a URL that uses the xip.io service. I'm excited. Perhaps the only remaining challenge: how to get other devices (eg iPhone) to trust the cert.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1032179/74576 helped me learn about `certutil`, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390363/470749 helped me when I got the "Active content with certificate errors" error.

Comment: @Ryan I've added a section about Windows, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you have to add your cert to the Trusted CA store. I let it auto decide and that did not work. Also I added it to my personal store which also did not work.

So the steps are (if you are on windows) is to hit your windows key and type in "Internet Options" and open well your internet options. Then click the "content" tab. From here click on "certificates" which is the middle button. 
[image]

Then click Import and Next. Browse to where you saved the cert.

Then click "Place all certificates in the following store" and click browse and select the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities".

[image]

And you should get a popup asking you to confirm and warning you and all that jazz.

And then make sure you restart your browser. On chrome you can type this into the URL bar: `chrome://restart`. Boom I hoped this helped you!

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/mwidmann/115c2a7059dcce300b61f625d887e5dc) is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the issuer is unknown. As you mentioned in the errors;
"This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate"
or
"This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)"

Lets first understand why this error occurs. The browsers have list of trusted certificate authorities. You can see this list from setting/preferences section of different browsers. If your certificate is not issued by one of these authorities, then you will get the above error.

FIXING IT ON LOCALHOST
I can think of two possible solutions;

1. Add the certificate manually to the browser and it will start opening with https.

OR

2. Sign the certificate with a already trusted authority. Install the certificates on local server. Configure host in /etc/hosts file with the same name of your domain against which you have signed the certificate.

I hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: I think I have tried #1 (but am not 100% sure what steps you are recommending) and am unclear about the steps for #2, too.

Comment: I agree with @Ryan in regards to step #1. I have tried adding the certificate manually but it still is not showing the green icon.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (works on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

1. Close your browser.
2. Get the Homestead `.crt` and `.key` content.

```bash
cd ~/Homestead
vagrant ssh
cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca.homestead.homestead.{crt,key}  <--  Copy that to clipboard
exit
```

3. From the `.crt` and `.key` content, create a `.pem` file and secure a copy of it into your Homestead folder.

```bash
cd ~/Homestead
mkdir .ssl
cd .ssl
nano ca.homestead.homestead.pem  <--  Paste the contents of the clipboard
```

4. Copy the `.pem` into your certificates folder, and refresh them.

```bash
cd ~/Homestead/.ssl
sudo cp -vR ca.homestead.homestead.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

5. Open your browser then add the CA certificates to the list of trusted ones.
6. Navigate to your website (via HTTPS) and it should be OK.