# Guzzle certification issue persists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, certificate, guzzle

I'm trying to post `reCaptcha` token vie `Guzzle` but it seems like there is a `certification` issue. I tried to handle it by myself. I copied `cacert.pem` into `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.11` folder and changed `;curl.cainfo` removed semicolon.

I tried the solution exactly as it was in this question: [cURL error 60: SSL certificate in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094842/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-4)

But unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. I'm sure I need to make some rearengements. hope somebody can help with that. This is the error I get:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

- Laravel 5.4
- Php 7.1.11

Comment: Any reason you're working with SSL on a WAMP server? It might be useful to switch to Homestead/Vagrant. Never had any problems, especially with the later versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263265/use-ssl-on-laravel-homestead?

Comment: I don't know, I guess I used to it